# Gitlab: Can't clone repo over SSH

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I've installed Gitlab version 5.1 on my server (Centos 6.4 64bit). After a lot of hiccups, I now can clone, pull and push... but only over HTTP. Anytime I try an SSH clone, this error occurs:

```
$ git clone git@git.server:my-project.git
Cloning into 'my-project'...
FATAL: R any my-project my-user DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This `DENIED by fallthru` error apparently is no stranger to Google and Stackoverflow, but most of them is Gitolite-related, which is not the case here, as Gitlab has dropped Gitolite as per v5. So what am I missing here? This is my first time working with Gitlab, so please be gentle.

Comment: Try: ssh git@git.server
to get the your permission on the server.

Comment: I tried that. User `git` can ssh into server without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after upgrading to 5.2 the problem's gone.